# Swift XCTest initiated code returns false let x = NSURL(string: urlString)

Tags: xcode, swift, swift-playground

In a swift Playground the following code works as expected with the url being set and the if clause being executed:

```swift
let query1 = "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search?queryRemoved";

if let url = NSURL(string: query1)
{
    println("Unwrapped url: [\(url)]") // Executes
}
```

In the App the code also works fine. But, in xCode running an XCTest that calls the same code, it fails:

```swift
    func requestQuestionsForPage(iPage: Int)
    {
        let query1 = "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search?queryRemoved";

        if let url = NSURL(string: query1)  // Evaluates to false???
        {
            let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
            let task = urlSession.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest, completionHandler: questionsHandler)
            task.resume()
        }
}
```

Changing to first set as an optional then testing for value, it works:

```swift
    func requestQuestionsForPage(iPage: Int)
    {
        let query1 = "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search?queryRemoved";

        let url = NSURL(string: query1)
        if (url != nil)
        {
            let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url!) // Unwrap here
        }
    }
```

I am clearly missing something here. Can anyone enlighten me as to why I'm seeing this behavior?

Comment: I just tried this in Xcode, and your first example works fine. Are you running this in an XCTest, or in an app? On the device, or the sim?

Comment: Your code is working for me..

Comment: Depending on your query string, you may run into issues. Have you tried `"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search?queryRemoved"` in your code or are you only showing that as an example?

Comment: Yes, I was running from an XCTest. I added code to run from the App and it both forms work there. When called from an XCTest, the **if let** version still fails. Isn't this odd?

Comment: I edited the question for clarity. Yes the url with queryRemoved is actually something like `https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search?page=1&pagesize=20&fromdate=2015-03-01&order=desc&sort=activity&intitle=iOS&filter=default&site=stackoverflow`